# What's the best way to compare one table's data against another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 select statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email
FROM         dbo.Customers
WHERE     (Email IS NOT NULL) 
AND (Email LIKE '%@%') 
AND (RIGHT(Email, 4) IN ('.net', '.com', '.org')) 
AND (Email NOT LIKE '%@UniformCity.com') 
AND (Email NOT LIKE '%@LifeUniform.com') 
AND (CHARINDEX('.',Email) <> 1)
AND (RIGHT(RTRIM(Email), 1) <> '.') AND (LEFT(LTRIM(Email), 1) <> '@') 
AND (Email not Like '%[`:;_*-,^[^]()+%\/=#-]%' escape '^') order by Email
```

AND

```
SELECT  replace(replace(
replace(
replace(EmailOptOut,'"','')
, ',held','')
, ',unsub','')
, ',confirm','') 
as CleanEmail
FROM [LifeMail].[dbo].[EmailOptOuts]
```

I only want to select the emails from the `Customers` table, THAT ARE NOT in the `EmailOptOuts` table.  What's the best way to achieve this?  I thought about using cursors and looping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to put these tables into temp tables, but you could combine the queries if you desired.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email
INTO    #tCustomersEmail
FROM    dbo.Customers
WHERE   ( Email IS NOT NULL )
    AND ( Email LIKE '%@%' )
    AND ( RIGHT(Email, 4) IN ( '.net', '.com', '.org' ) )
    AND ( Email NOT LIKE '%@UniformCity.com' )
    AND ( Email NOT LIKE '%@LifeUniform.com' )
    AND ( CHARINDEX('.', Email) <> 1 )
    AND ( RIGHT(RTRIM(Email), 1) <> '.' )
    AND ( LEFT(LTRIM(Email), 1) <> '@' )
    AND ( Email NOT LIKE '%[`:;_*-,^[^]()+%\/=#-]%' ESCAPE '^' )
ORDER BY Email

SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(EmailOptOut, '"', ''), ',held', ''),',unsub', ''), ',confirm', '') AS CleanEmail
INTO #tOptOuts
FROM    [LifeMail].[dbo].[EmailOptOuts]

SELECT Email
FROM #tCustomersEmail AS tce
WHERE Email NOT IN (SELECT CleanEmail FROM #tOptOuts AS too)
```

Answer (score 3):

Bypassing your cleanup rules just so that the code below is cleaner, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT c.Email
    FROM dbo.Customers c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM [LifeMail].[dbo].[EmailOptOuts] o
                         WHERE c.Email = o.EmailOptOut)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
SELECT Email     
FROM dbo.Customers      
WHERE Email NOT IN 
    ( SELECT Email                          
      FROM [LifeMail].[dbo].[EmailOptOuts]                          
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

1 more solution (with `LEFT JOIN`) :

```
SELECT Email     
FROM dbo.Customers  c
LEFT JOIN [LifeMail].[dbo].[EmailOptOuts] b ON (b.EmailOptOut = c.Email)
WHERE b.EmailOptOut IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT qCustomerEmail.Email 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Email
    FROM         dbo.Customers
    WHERE     (Email IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (Email LIKE '%@%') 
    AND (RIGHT(Email, 4) IN ('.net', '.com', '.org')) 
    AND (Email NOT LIKE '%@UniformCity.com') 
    AND (Email NOT LIKE '%@LifeUniform.com') 
    AND (CHARINDEX('.',Email) <> 1)
    AND (RIGHT(RTRIM(Email), 1) <> '.') AND (LEFT(LTRIM(Email), 1) <> '@') 
    AND (Email not Like '%[`:;_*-,^[^]()+%\/=#-]%' escape '^')) qCustomerEmail
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT  replace(replace(
    replace(
    replace(EmailOptOut,'"','')
    , ',held','')
    , ',unsub','')
    , ',confirm','') 
    as CleanEmail
    FROM [LifeMail].[dbo].[EmailOptOuts]) qOptOut
ON qCustomerEmail.Email = qOptOut.CleanEmail
WHERE qOptOut.CleanEmail IS NULL
```